# does --expose-gc stops the garbage collector from being executed automatically?

Tags: node.js, garbage-collection

I want to be able to execute garbage collections manually, but I don't want to stop nodejs for automatically executing gc when it thinks it's relevant.

does --expose-gc stops automatic gc execution ?

if I do want to stop automatic gc execution what parameter I need to add ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it merely exposes a global `gc()` function to allow you to force the garbage collector to run.